how to create tv playing cartoon in blender and export it to a model?
I am attempting to create a TV that plays cartoons using video.mp4, and after completing this, I aim to export it as a GLB format file. However, when I perform these steps, the video does not play, and the mp4 file seems to be missing when I import it again for viewing.
